# Звездный рейтинг

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Помогите, делаю звездный рейтинг по [этому](http://www.shkolovy.com/blog/article/17) примеру, но у меня при нажатии на звездочку подгружает страницу ошибки, делаю проект на asp.net mvc.

Comment: пример бы того, как Вы это делаете.

Comment: делаю, так как написано в тутолиале 
http://inphotofocus.com/Galleries/PhotoShowed/105
тут можно посмотреть как не работает =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, Вы только начали изучение MVC. Дело в том, что у Вас в коде:

```
$('#rating').rater('Handler.ashx',{ maxvalue: 10, style: 'basic', curvalue: '0'});
```

идёт обращение к файлу **Handler.ashx**, который к **MVC** никакого отношения не имеет.
Раз уж Вы используете **MVC**, то Вам необходимо в контроллере, предположим "**Home**" создать функцию, которая будет принимать какие - то параметры, и возвращать результат в виде обычной строки:

```
public string Rating(string rating)
{
    string result="";
    //тут мы обрабатываем какие - то события, делаем запись в Базу Данных.
    return result; //возвращаем ответ.
}
```

и затем вызвать:

```
$('#rating').rater('Home/Rating',{ maxvalue: 10, style: 'basic', curvalue: '0'});
```

*P.S. т.к. функция **Rating** не является **ActionResult**, для неё создавать представление(**View**) НЕ НАДО.*

Comment: хорошо, но как тогда прикрутить об туда функционал класса Handler.ashx, что бы он принял HttpContext, и вернул   context.Response.Write("ответ"); ? 
уже пару дней мучаюсь с этим рейтингом, а пару недель как взялся за MVC

Comment: context.Response.Write("ответ"); в данном случае не нужен.
при вызове 
rater('Home/__Rating__',{ maxvalue: 10, style: 'basic', curvalue: '0'});

Вызывается функция public string __Rating__(string rating), которая принимает значение rating. 

Попробуйте сделать так:

    public string Rating(string rating)
    {
        string result=starClass.starMethod(rating);
        return result; //возвращаем ответ.
    }

Comment: большое спасибо, наконец-то домучал эту задачу )

Comment: Заработало? А то я уже проект собрался создавать. )

Comment: да, начало возвращать оценку, теперь, если есть идея, подскажи, как можно все это записать в таблицу? т.е. оценку я получаю, как мне ее привязать к айди фотографии? тоже передавать его надо?

Comment: Да, передавай оценку и айди и записывай оценку в таблицу с айдишником новости. )
Всё просто. )

Comment: посидел, подумал =) я без понятия пока, каким способом можно передать еще и айди записи, т.е. вроде бы она и передается, но как ее отловить контроллером я не знаю